# How do I manipulate arrays created from a match.find?

Tags: java, arrays, regex, match

Here is the code I have:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.*;


public class EmailReader {


public static void main(String args[]) {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    try {
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect   ("imap.gmail.com", "email@gmail.com", "password");
        System.out.println(store);

        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages();


        for (Message message : messages) {
            String subject = message.getSubject();
            String location = "AAR|RRC|PSD|TPC|HP|SCC|MCA";
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            System.out.println("SUBJECT:  " + subject);
            System.out.println("DATE:  " + message.getSentDate());
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(location);
            Matcher match = pattern.matcher(subject);
            while (match.find()) {
                list.add(match.group());
                System.out.println(list);
            }



        }
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(2);
    }
}
}
```

I want the program to read each email while searching for the strings saved in locations and store these in an array.  This works fine, however I would like each of the abbreviations in the location string be set to an value for determining mileage.  I have no idea how I would go about this.  In the end I want to be able to sum up all the values from a certain date range of emails based on the numbers found.  So, for example, if AAR was set to 15 and showed up in 3 email subject lines and RRC was set to 8 and showed up in 2, it would sum it all up and print it out.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using:
   if(match.group().contains("AAR"){ 
    Then do this string of code
    }
It looks pretty sloppy since I have a bunch of if statements but works.  Might be better to use a switch instead.